# Get the new URL on window.popstate

Tags: javascript, popstate

Is there any way I can get the new page's url when the `window.popstate` is fired?

```
window.onpopstate(function (){
    newPageUrl = //get the new page's URL
})
```

Comment: Doesn't `location.href` work?

Comment: window.location.href.toString().split(window.location.host)[‌​1]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this

```
window.onpopstate = function (){
    newPageUrl = location.href;
}
```

Comment: This is the right syntax: 
window.onpopstate = function() {

}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: basically the route-change has registered by the time the event callback is hit. So the currentUrl is the newUrl already